# Retrieve data from Firebase upon User Interaction

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firebase, I have 'GS' collection with +10 fields in it.
I have listed these fields with code below. My purpose is to allow User to select one of the field, and show which field is selected.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('GS').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data');
        return Column(

                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset("assets/GS.png",
            scale: 5.0,),
            onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.GS);}, //Answers.GS will be selected.
            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['man'],  //A string from database. After selection, I would like to show this string.

             ),
          ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
```

When User selects an item from the list, I would like to show it. My structure works. But, it could not achieve to show the selected field. I would like to update the `_setValue(//here)` code below with retrieving data from firebase:

```
           {
  case Answers.GS:
  _setValue('Selected string from database'); //I just want to update this code with what is written inside "man" in Firebase. 
  break;
}
```

Let's say in Firebase, under "man" is written 'I love Flutter'. I would like to show that.

As a summary: I would like to do something like that `_setValue(snapshot.data.documents[0]['man'])`. Obviously, I am getting error with this.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking. It will be helpful for others to understand if you include what you have tried and explain in more detail.

Comment: @SteveKim I have provided more detail. Please take a look! Thanks for your time.